# Is a wireless acces point always wired to a router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wired

The wireless acces point (WAP) needs to connect to a router for internet connection. Is it possible to connect the WAP wireless to a router?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Wim, welcome to SU.  Please [edit] your question and provide more detail about what you need.  The question is likely to be closed as not answerable as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Another router can function as an access point. It will receive signals from the primary router wirelessly (if so configured) and then send out the signals within its own radius.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaM_-jM1Rxg&list=UUyNkVYbRm9622gDSIVRpE7g&index=3&feature=plcp